# How to resolve reference errors in Code Analysis of MVC.net project using Team City

Tags: asp.net-mvc, continuous-integration, teamcity, resharper

When using Team City for CI builds there is an option to use the Resharper command line tools to run Code Analysis inspection of the code as one of the build steps.

I have this working with reference library projects but the mvc.net project in the solution fails with reference errors:

> One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be
>   found. Are you missing references to Microsoft.CSharp.dll and
>   System.Core.dll?

Even with the default Microsoft template there are over 200 errors and they seem to all come from the razor views. (The project compiles and deploys from the build server correctly and FXCop also runs successfully, this seems to be an issue just for resharper tool.)

I can run the resharper code inspection in visual studio without errors.

In Team City I just have a default Inspection (.NET) build running pointing at the .sln file.

We are using Resharper Command Line Tools 9.1.201 as provided with TeamCity 9.0.4

What configuration or additional steps can I take to get the resharper command line tool to resolve mvc view references on the build server?

If resolving the references is not possible, can the razor views be excluded from the analysis without needing to add each exclusion to the command line?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I just had the same issue. Digging through the build log, I noticed a seemingly unrelated warning:

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found.

I retargeted my project to .NET 4.6 and installed the .NET 4.6 targeting pack, and the code inspection errors are gone. Unfortunately, I don't know if just installing the .NET 4.5.2 targeting pack would have solved the issue.